# ListBox with 2 Row Data

Tags: wpf, listbox

I want to design a music player with ListBox has 2 rows to show songs.
But i don't know how to do this with DataTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Examples section in [ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) for what you can do with a DataTemplate.

What you want to do here could be done by setting the [ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) property of your ListBox. Without having tested that, i would suggest to use a [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx) with [Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.rows.aspx) set to 2.

Comment: I followed that section but ListBox cannot show data with 2 Rows.
Please see this photo http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/69/jukeboxwide.jpg/ as you can see, the AlbumList is shown by ListBox with 2 Rows Data and have a function to Next, Previous AlbumList - i'm also stuck too

Comment: Ok, then you should look into [ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx).

Comment: Oh thanks, now i can see my ListBox show Albums with multiple Rows but how do i set DataTemplate or ItemsPanel to show exactly 2 Rows and navigate to other with Next, Previous button.
Regards.